# Php uploads incorrect files also

Tags: php, file-upload

**Whats my problem with this code:**

As you can see, I allow only image files from the `$fajl_types` array.
But if I select a `txt` or some other file, it will also be uploaded. I get the error, that incorrect file type, but it will be uploaded anyway.

What am II doing wrong? Should I put a `if(count($error) == 0 )` before the `move_upload_file` function or what?

```
$error = array();
$fajl_types = array(
                    'png'  => 'image/png',
                    'jpe'  => 'image/jpeg',
                    'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
                    'jpg'  => 'image/jpeg',
                    'gif'  => 'image/gif',
                    'bmp'  => 'image/bmp'
                );

if(isset($_POST['send_kapcsolat'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['hiba_nev'])) {
        $error[] = "Name required";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['hiba_email'])){
        $error[] = "Email required.";
    }

    if(isset($_FILES['hiba_file']) && $_FILES["hiba_file"]['size'] != 0 )
    {
        if($_FILES["hiba_file"]["size"] > 5242880 ) { 
            $error[] = "File size is max 5 mb."; 
        }
        $filename = $_FILES["hiba_file"]['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $fajl_types)) { 
            $error[] = "Incorrect file type"; 
        } 
        $path = "hiba/" . date( "Y-m-d-H:i:s" ) . '-' . rand(1, 9999) . '-' . $_FILES["hiba_file"]['name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["hiba_file"]['tmp_name'], $path ))
        {
            $hiba_file = basename($path);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $hiba_file = "";
    }

    if(count($error) == 0 )
    {
        $hiba_nev = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $_POST['hiba_nev']);
        $hiba_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $_POST['hiba_email']);
        $hiba_uzenet = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $_POST['hiba_uzenet']);
        $hiba_status = (int)0;
        $hiba_date = date("Y-m-d-H:i:s");

        $sql = 
        "
            INSERT INTO hiba
            (
                hiba_nev,
                hiba_email,
                hiba_uzenet,
                hiba_file,
                hiba_status,
                hiba_date
            )
            VALUES
            (
                '".$hiba_nev."',
                '".$hiba_email."',
                '".$hiba_uzenet."',
                '".$hiba_file."',
                '".$hiba_status."',
                '".$hiba_date."'
            )
        ";
        print_r($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not exiting your code when you find that the type is wrong, you just set an error message and then go right ahead and move the file anyway!

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: _Should I put a if(count($error) == 0 ) before the move_upload_file function_ **That sounds like a plan!** So you answered your own question, make me wonder why you didn't just try that and save yourself the time involved in asking a question

Comment: _Small Note:_ `$sql` is a string and therefore an `echo $sql;` would be better than a `print_r($sql)`;` as `$sql` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
if(!array_key_exists($ext, $fajl_types)) { $error[] = "Incorrect file type"; }
```

Check if count of errors is 0 and then execute the rest of the code until the end of the main If branch that checks if files are set.

The error is that if statement

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["hiba_file"]['tmp_name'], $path ))
```

Uploads your files and is executed even if the errors occur.

Comment: And isnt that a problem, that now i have two count($error)==0 in the code?

Comment: No, because you must set some value to variable $hiba_file before executing sql. The if statement does not require much resources so you will be fine I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code in:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["hiba_file"]['tmp_name'], $path ))
{
$hiba_file = basename($path);
}
```

this if:

```
if(count($error) == 0 )
```

Because right now you upload your file even if error does exist,but you should do it only if error count is 0.